# Wix shortcut desktop - is this code for current user or all users

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, shortcut

I am trying to create a shortcut for all users using **Wix 3.6**. My **InstallScope** is **perMachine** and **InstallPriviledges** is **elevated**. I build this code ok. It runs ok. Does this produce a shortcut for all users or just the current user and what do I need to change to make a shortcut for all users?

```xml
<DirectoryRef Id="DesktopFolder">
  <Component Id="ApplicationDesktopShortcut" Guid="*">
    <Shortcut Id="MyClient_DesktopShortcut" Name="My Client" 
              Description="My Client" Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]MyClient.exe" 
              WokingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\MyServices\My Client\DesktopShortcut"
                   Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Thanks
Jason

Comment: This depends on the setting used for the [**ALLUSERS property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367559(v=vs.85).aspx). Please read this answer: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29255922/how-can-i-create-a-shortcut-on-the-users-desktop-folder/29498210#29498210**